# register_settings callback function erases data

Tags: user-registration, options, callbacks

I have registered a setting with a callback function:

```
register_setting( 'my-plugin-settings-group', 'notification_email', 'email_validation' )
```

and callback function looks like:

```
function email_validation($data) {

    if (null == $data)
    {
        add_settings_error(
            'requiredTextFieldEmpty',
            'empty',
            'Notification Email cannot be empty',
            'error'
        );
    }
    else {

        if (!is_email($data)){
            add_settings_error(
                'requiredTextFieldEmpty',
                'empty',
                'Notification Email is not valid email address',
                'error'
            );
        }

        else { return $data; }
    }
}
```

Validation works fine but when it fails (empty field or not valid email address) it erases data from that field.

Is there any way to prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case of wrong value, the function has to return the original value then try this :

```
function email_validation($data, $option, $original_value) {

    if (null == $data)
    {
        add_settings_error(
            'requiredTextFieldEmpty',
            'empty',
            'Notification Email cannot be empty',
            'error'
        );

        return $original_value;
    }
    else {

        if (!is_email($data)){
            add_settings_error(
                'requiredTextFieldEmpty',
                'empty',
                'Notification Email is not valid email address',
                'error'
            );

            return $original_value;
        }

        else { return $data; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The idea is right but it came that `$original_value` is empty when that function was called.

Comment: I have added `$original_value =  esc_attr( get_option('notification_email') );` as a first line of the function to get it work.